# Animation to move an element does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm testing a simple animation to move the text

```
<hmtl>
    <style>
     #work{
        background-color:blue;
        width:50px;
        position:absolute;
        left:50px;

    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="work">Animation Area</div>
        <script>
            elem=document.getElementById("work");
            function move(){
                if(elem.style.left < 500){
                    elem.style.left=(elem.style.left+10)+'px';
                    setTimeout(move,20);
                }
            }
            move();
        </script>
    </body>
</hmtl>
```

In this simple code I cant find where I made a mistake. What I get is only a text at a default location but it doesn't move. why?

Comment: For starters, `elem.style.left` does not return a number, it returns something like `"500px"`

Comment: Secondly, the element has no position nor a starting left value

Comment: `<hmtl>` should be `<html>`

Comment: when added still dont work

Comment: Thirdly, external styles aren't returned in `elem.style`

Comment: I've edited your post to remove potentially offensive text. Please keep it clean whenever you can.

Comment: Fourthly, even if you were changing the left value of that element, unless its position was absolute or fixed(based on what you have here) you wouldn't notice it move.

Comment: you want to do it in native JavaScript for a reason? Because there are libraries that can help you out. Example: jQuery, Greensock, move, velocity, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a bunch of mistakes, after some debugging, the console revealed `style.left` returns null. Set it to any value and it works fine

[I'll leave you with this](http://jsbin.com/vixaqohopo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use marginLeft
2. start marginLeft with a value
3. When you get the marginLeft value, you should parse the value to INT

   ```
       <div style="margin-left:0px" id="work">JAVASCRIPT ANIMATE</div>
       <script>
           var elem = document.getElementById("work");
           function move(){

               var intLeft = parseInt(elem.style.marginLeft);

               if(intLeft < 500){
                   elem.style.marginLeft=(intLeft+10) + 'px';
                   setTimeout(move,20);
               }
           }
           move();
       </script>
   ```